# Saving space on Drive C to Linux

Tags: linux, windows

I want to have install Linux on a machine with windows. For dual boot, I want to use UNetbootin, which only show me the option to install the iso in drive C. The point is:

1) My drive C is almost full (115/118gb)

2) I have more 3 empty drives with 300gb.

3) I am considering 35gb for Linux.

If I clean and transfer all my files and backups from drive C, I got 15gb in free space but still not enough for Ubuntu 18.
I would like to know, which other files (among program and system files) I could move from the default drive C? Any suggestion?

Comment: Uh, are you sure UNetbootin actually installs a proper dual-boot OS? It's generally only made for making bootable USBs – so it wouldn't be installing a full OS but just making the computer boot the "live" system... (A full dual-boot OS wouldn't install to "drive C" in the first place – it would have _its own_ partitions.) Overall this plan sounds a bit strange.

Comment: Sorry maybe I did not explained well. But if you look at https://unetbootin.github.io you can see it, there is a option to choose USB of hard drive, and in this case just the drive C.

Comment: The tool will place a *bootable installer* there (that may or may not be used as a *live* OS, depending on the image you have). Then, to actually install Linux you will need to boot from the chosen device and pick *yet another location*. It seems you're on a good way to wipe your Windows in vain. When you say "3 empty drives", do you mean partitions or separate disks? Probably partitions, since UNetbootin doesn't let you choose them; but please confirm. A good way is to create a bootable USB pendrive, boot it and install to empty partition(s) without even touching Windows system partition.

Comment: Thanks Kamil. Yes, I will do it, make a bootable USB. There is a another point here: I said drivers but you are correct, I wanted to mean partitions. But actually, C is a separated SSD with all system files and programs. So, can I still install the distro on the other drive within any of the empty partitions?

Comment: Yes, a proper Linux installation media will install the OS on any disk you like and take care of the dual-boot. But have you looked at [Ubuntu](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6#activetab=pivot:overviewtab) in the Microsoft Store which avoids the dual-boot headache?

Comment: Thanks. I know that now MS support Ubuntu but I did not check it  carefully. I was thinking to go through dual boot exactly to avoid future problems, so I choose to have a full install instead ubuntu over windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install a new OS, you have to be sure that your HDD have enough `continuos space`. You can use the `defragment tool` provided by Windows, be sure to `defragment the empty space as contiguos space` for have a suitable "piece of data" for install the system.

Comment: Thanks. Now I want to know, for the case of dual boot, can I install the SO in empty partition in one drive while Windows is installed in another drive (SSD)?

Comment: Of course, linux is smart enough to write the boot loader on the master bot records, no matter how many disk there are (: